# Switch Matlab workspaces in the debugging mode

Tags: matlab, debugging, workspace

I am using Matlab R2017a. In earlier versions, there used to be an option, while in the debug mode, to switch the workspaces amongst calling functions in order to examine the values of the variables in the respective workspaces. I can not find the control in this current version Matlab R2017a. How does one switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function call stack dropdown is on the editor tab while your program is stopped in the debugger:

[image]

You can also use [`dbstack`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstack.html), [`dbup`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbup.html), and [`dbdown`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbdown.html) to list the stacks and navigate through them via the command window.